# php header redirect does not work

Tags: php, redirect, header

Here is the code:

```
    <?php 
        $curDate = date("r",strtotime("now"));

        if($database->addNewSale($_SESSION['username'],$_SESSION['userid'], $_SESSION['cart'],$curDate) ==10){

            //Some of the offers in the cart have expired and cannot be purchased!
            header("Location: ../order/index.php");

            exit;


            } else if($database->addNewSale($_SESSION['username'],$_SESSION['userid'], $_SESSION['cart'],$curDate)){
                echo "insert process ok";

            }

                else echo "sale has not been saved into the db";

         ?>
```

But, when the function `addNewSale` returns `10` which is the code for error in cart, the redirect header function does not actually redirect to the page I set.

Comment: Is the space before the `<?php` tag just something you wrote here, or is actually in your page too? Any error? (what error_reporting level have you set?)

Comment: Does it redirect at all?  Which page *does* it go to?  Is it possible ../order/index.php doesn't exist and you're being bounced again to a 404 page for example?

Comment: @george is this in a class? as your treating the function like a method

Comment: Ok this is weird: On my MAMP localhost server it does not redirect. I tried it on the WAMP localhost in my laptop and it works!! I have no idea what is going on!

Comment: I got no warnings or errors btw.

Comment: Your posted code seems to contain leading white space before the first `<?php`. If it was copied correctly then yes, you should see a `headers already sent` warning, unless error reporting/display errors is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
header("Location: ../order/index.php");
```

But the location header is required to be a full absolute URL. I don't know if this is your problem but even if it happens to work it's not correct.

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html section 14.30

Comment: In addition, the `header` function **must** be called before any output is produced.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any warnings? header() failures are most commonly caused by the "headers already sent" warning, which can be caused by whitespace (can't have any of it above your php opening tag) or anything else that would be emitting to an html page. Check to make sure your text editor isn't saving it with byte order marks (BOM) - this causes the exact same problem as having errant whitespace. You can try turning output buffering on (ob_start() - just be sure to ob_end_flush() when you're done.)

Answer (score 0):

First try with

```
   if(result=='10')//use single quotes
    otherwise
      use full location path
    $path="index.php";
    header("Location:$path");
```

Comment: `==` is not a type match so I don't see why enclosing a number in apostrophes is going to help in this situation.